# Does Conrad Verner make an appearance in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Our favorite wanna-be Spectre Conrad annoyed us for two games straight, and I'm curious as to whether or not he's back for a third round to once again irritate Commander Shepard to death. If he **does** make an appearance, what role does he play? Is there an associated side mission involving him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conrad Verner makes an appearance on the Citadel, coming up to Shepard after you assist a doctor with his medi-gel station problem in the refugee camp. After you both exchange a few words, he'll somewhat inexplicably shout at a supposed Cerberus agent who will in turn fire upon Shepard.

Verner will then

> play the hero, jumping to take the bullet for Shepard in what to me seemed so awkwardly choreographed that originally I had thought he had set the whole thing up. However, it's a real threat, and he will die.

Unless you helped save Jenna from Chora's Den in Mass Effect 1, that is. If you did, she'll be there to

> interfere with the agent's gun, causing it to not actually shoot anything. Conrad will then realize that he's alright, and he'll leave Shepard alone to go use his legitimately gained life-saver status to try and pick up Jenna.

Answer (score 2):

Yes he makes an appearance in one of the citadel missions and I believe he has the possibility to die if you hadn't done one of the citadel side missions in Mass Effect 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to Mass Effect 3's lead writer, Mac Walters, Conrad Verner will be in Mass Effect 3 (as long as he didn't die in Mass Effect 2).

> Q. In ME 2, Conrad Verner seems to the think that Shepard held a gun to his face, even if players chose the paragon option in ME 1. Was this just a glitch, or is there some story reason behind this?
>
> A. Well, it may have been a glitch, or maybe Conrad was just having an off day (even more off than usual). Stay tuned in Mass Effect 3 to see how Verner deals with this embarrassing misstep with Shepard.

[Source](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2011/04/21/mass-effect-a-q-amp-a-for-hardcore-fans.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, but I was also hoping to know what role he'd be playing in the game. If that information is edited in at a later date, I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: I haven't run into him in the game yet, but I'll certainly update when I do. I'm just hoping that I didn't let him die in ME2, my last playthrough of it was a long time ago and I don't remember what fate befell that lovable(?) pest.